# Yii2 how to block access for URL if other registered user is on that URL?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My today goal is to make URL unavailable to other registered users if one of the user opened that URL and make it available when this user leaves it. Right now I have only idea how to block it - using cache, but problem is with unblocking as user can go everywhere or even just close the browser. I know that there is option for set cache timer, but in my case this is NOT an option - system must know if there is some user in that URL. Can someone help me with some ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: The main issue with this is that HTTP is not designed in a way that would allow server "to know" if the user is still in page. It's designed to serve the page and then pretty much forget about it. There are ways to emulate some tracking, for example you can have JS pinging some url at server in constant interval, to let the server know that user is there or you can use websocket to do something similar. But even those can fail for example because of network issues while the page is still open in user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can personally think of is using JWT or sessions to check if a logged in user is on that page, then a condition to check if the current user is not equal user that is trying to get on the page, and if it doesn't match just redirect that user to somewhere else.

```js
export const blockAccess = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  //check if the user is currently on the page
  if (req.session.promoPage) {
    //if they are, redirect new user's that're trying to access the page to the home page
    if (req.session.promoPage.userId !== req.user.id) {
      res.redirect('/')
    }
  }
  next() //next here is a function that tells the program to move on to the next middleware function or route etc....
})
```